# Casting error? Arrays and objects for my homework

Tags: java, arrays

I was tasked to create a command line app that manages baseball teams. One of the methods is clone and compare to but the header is

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

I have a class file called team which default constructor is an array of players (Player []) and another class file that constructs player. This is my compare to method so far.

```
Player player4 = (Player) obj;

player4.mutateErrors(2);
player4.mutateHits(3);
player4.mutateName("james");
```

And i get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to cse214hw1.Player
>       at cse214hw1.CSE214HW1.main(CSE214HW1.java:42)
>   Java Result: 1

Any ideas?

Comment: Not my compare method, ultimately want to know why i cant cast this

Comment: Show us you relevant code. Its not enough to help. But one is correct, you are converting Object to Player.

Comment: It appears that the object that the `obj` references at the time that this method is called is in fact not a Player object but rather an Object object. Without more context, I'm not sure how we can help further.

Comment: Or you could simply ignore our requests for more context, for more help in understanding your problem. Voting to close as an unanswerable question in its present condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think some information is missing and a correct and precise answer cannot be given, but my guess is that you are not passing an actual `Player` object to that method.

You can verify using `instanceof`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Player) {
        // Compare here
    }
    return false; // Cannot be equal, different types
}
```